# PSpice Op Amp Capture Problems

Tags: library, orcad

I am designing a circuit in OrCAD 16.5.  I have added the libraries in the "place part" section and have used the LM837 and LT1115 Op Amps.  When I create my netlist, I am getting the warning "No PSpiceTemplate for U5B, ignoring" and the parts do not appear in the netlist.  It appears that I do not have the libraries for these files, but I dont know how to add them (or where to get them from).  I assumed they were in OrCAD as I was able to place the part.  Can someone help me out with this problem?

Answer (score 1):

you can get PSPICE model from manufacturer company, search on google for example "LM239 PSPICE Model" this will lead you to texas instrument site datasheet page. scroll down and you will see they have provided with PSPICE model.

I've found [a guide](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa070/sloa070.pdf) in the TI's website.